# dropdown hidden behind modal and unclickable with nz-zorro

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, modal-dialog, ng-zorro-antd

couple days ago i update my app to angular 9, and now i sometimes see broken elements.
i am using ng-zorro\angular material.

i get problem when nz-select drop-down disapear behind screen.

html:

```
         <div>
            <nz-select  [(ngModel)]="exampleSelectedValue">
                <nz-option
                    nzLabel="{{item.description || 'Example ' + (i+1)}}" nzValue="{{i}}" *ngFor="let item of data.metadata.examples; let i= index"></nz-option>
            </nz-select>
        </div>
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Have you tried to increase z-index of element ?

Comment: yea, did not work

Comment: can u share what u tried please?

Comment: just to display the drop down

Comment: You can  solve by editing css in style.css, not in component.css. Find the corret element and increase z-index in style.css

Comment: I have the same issue, have you reported this issue in official site?

Comment: Have you found a solution?
Actually I understand this is more complicated theta what it seems. Because the options are hidden behind the cdk layer and the select component is actually under the modal component. Why, don't know.
Did you get somewhere with this?